# Como formatar uma String com outros elementos utilizando format()

Tags: java, string

Gostaria de saber como formatar uma String 08041995 em 08/04/1995
utilizando o método format() em Java

```
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(arq);
    String valor = "250,35";
    ps.format("R$ "+"%s", valor);
    ps.flush();
```

Consegui inserir uma String (R$) no início da String (valor), mas inserir elementos dentre uma String, como as barras... não sei.

Como fazer? Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Você não vai conseguir usar o `String.format` para isso, mas você pode quebrar a string em 3 partes (usando `substring`) para tal:

```
String valor = "08041995";
String formatado = valor.substring(0, 2) + "/" +
                   valor.substring(2, 4) + "/" +
                   valor.substring(4, 8);
```

Comment: Seria ainda melhor se você criasse um formatador customizado estendendo a classe java.text.Format pra encapsular a lógica dessa conversão dentro dele e reusá-lo dentro do teu código.